# Reload database value after back button

Tags: android, sql, variables, refresh

On my homescreen I am getting a certain value out of my DB (item out table where a field active=1):

```
String s2 = "Logged in as " + myDbHelper.getActivePlayer();
bPlayQuiz.setText(s2);
```

When I click to my settings activity, change the player, another player gets field active=1. So when I hit the back button, the first value is still there... Any idea how to code this that it will refresh when I come back on my homescreen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always reload the field in the `onResume`, which is called whenever the activity regains focus:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    String s2 = "Logged in as " + myDbHelper.getActivePlayer();
    bPlayQuiz.setText(s2);
}
```

There's more information about the resume part of the lifecycle [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).